# Counting number of polygons within which points are located using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, count, general-transit-feed-specification, service-area

I have used the network analyst to calculate service areas of varying facilities.  Additionally I have points which represent buildings.

To make it short, I have the following data:

- Polygons - which represent service areas
- Points - which represent buildings

Is there a possbility to determine which buildings have access to zero, one, two, etc. etc. facilities?

In my understatement that would mean to to count the number of polygons in which a certain point is located.

How can I do that?

I am using ArcMap 10.6 with an advanced desktop license.

Comment: See [How To: Add a field containing a count of overlapping features in another layer](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008877)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned Esri Blog Post with the Spaghetti and Meatballs (More adventures in overlay: counting overlapping polygons with spaghetti and meatballs by Dan Honeycutt) approach delivered exactly what I needed and was very convenient. With the help of the Esri Support I was able to rebuild the model and it worked. The result in the end looked like this:
[image: Result of Spaghetti and Meatball Toolbox: Join_Count describes the number of overlapping polygons]

With a spatial join I should now be able to add the inhabitants to each polygon.

Answer (score 1):

There is Spatial join for this.

Your data are in database or on PC?

If first, I would recommend you to use [ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html), this is the most natural way to realise your idea. The query to run is smth like

```
with new_values as 
(SELECT count(poly), poi.id from your_schema.polygons_with_facilities as poly 
JOIN your_schema.buildings as poi on 
    st_contains(poly.geom, poi.geom) group by poi.id)
UPDATE your_schema.buildings as b
SET field_for_counted_polys = nv.count from new_values nv where nv.id = b.id;
```

if your data are not in DB, try [this approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=solq8CuCbow)

Comment: My data are on my own PC.
I think the solution here is to first use the spaghetti and meatballs approach and then perform a spatial join.
First the spaghetti and meatballs approach delivers me the information how many areas overlap in each polygon.

Comment: There is a Esri Blog post on that topic: "More adventures in overlay: counting overlapping polygons with spaghetti and meatballs".
Afterwards a spatial join with the points provides the information I am looking for. The information I am looking for is which household are within one, two, etc. etc. service areas.
I am not done yet, let's see if it works.